# Yii Framework Similar Function to POST and GET

Tags: php, yii, code-duplication

can anyone convert this code into the yii framework?

file name: text.php

```
<form method='POST' action='index.php'>
<input type='text' name='name'>
<input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'>
</form>
```

then the text in the text will be viewed in the index.

file name: index.php

```
$text=$_POST['name'];
echo "$text";
```

Can anyone implement this code in Yii? and what is also the code used for using GET method , assuming that the index.php will be the controller and the text.php will be the view file

(what i am trying to achieve here is to pass the value of the textbox named as 'name' to the controller)?

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii form generation:

```
<?= CHtml::beginForm( array("controller/action") ) ?>
<?= CHtml::textField("name", "") ?>
<?= CHtml::endForm() ?>
```

[Yii CHtml docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml)

Also you need implement CModel or CForm class to validate form.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$_POST['name']` in your controller to get the value, just like you did it.

If you do it with the GET method, it would rather be a parameter of a method in your controller:

```
public function actionSomething($name) {
    ...
}
```